# DRF: Manipulating serializer field layout

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model that represents a house:

```
class House(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    long = models.FloatField(...)
    lat = models.FloatField(...)
```

and a serializer to return a list of houses in their *most basic* representation:

```
class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = House
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

and the view

```
class HouseList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = House.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HouseSerializer
```

this works fine. I can visit `/api/house/` and I see a json list of houses:

```
{ 
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Big House'
},
{
    'id': 1
    'name': 'Small House',
}...
```

Now I want to create a second view/resource at `/api/maps/markers/` that returns my houses as a list of Google-Map-Friendly markers of the format:

```
{ 
    'id': 1,
    'long': ...,
    'lat': ...,
    'houseInfo': {
        'title': "Big House",
    }
} ...
```

I can foresee two approaches:

- perform this as a separate serializer (using the same view as before) and mapping out the alternative field layout.
- perform this  as a separate view (using the same serializer as before) and simply layout the fields before creating a `Response`

but in neither approach am I clear on how to go about it nor which approach is preferable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer 1**

Looks to me like you need both - different view and serializer.

Simply because the view endpoint is not a sub-url of the first one, so they are not related - different view, even if they use the same model.

And different serializer - since you have a different field layout.

Not really sure how complicated is your case, but any code duplication can probably be solved by mixins anyway.

**Answer 2**

Depending on the use case:

- if you also need to write data using the same struct, you need to define your own field class and handle the parsing correctly
- if it's just reading data, you should be fine with this:

  ```
  class HouseGoogleSerializer(HouseSerializer):
      houseInfo = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_house_info')

      class Meta:
          model = House
          fields = [...]

      def get_house_info(self, obj):
          return {'title': obj.name}
  ```

  where `HouseSerializer` is your base house serializer.

Comment: How can I manipulate the field layout in the serializer though so that I have a nested `houseInfo` object?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony see my updates, hope it helps. I could find few ways to manipulate the layout, this one seems most flexible and clean.

Answer (score 1):

this code come from a running project and offer somethig more that you ask
but can easily adapted for your need if you want remove some features.
The current implemetation allow you:

- use only one url one serializer and one view
- choose the output using query string param (?serializer=std)

how to use in your code:

**Case 1** (one url with ability to choose the serializer via querystring)

```
class HouseSerializer(HouseSerializer):
    houseInfo = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_house_info')

    class Meta:
        model = House

    def get_house_info(self, obj):
        return {'title': obj.name}


class HouseList(DynamicSerializerMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = House.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HouseSerializer
    serializers_fieldsets = {'std': ('id', 'name'),
                              'google' : ('id', 'long', 'lat', 'houseInfo')}
```

**Case 2** (different views)

```
class HouseList(DynamicSerializerMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = House.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HouseSerializer
    serializers_fieldsets = {'std': ('id', 'name')}

class GoogleHouseList(DynamicSerializerMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = House.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HouseSerializer
    serializers_fieldsets = {'std': ('id', 'long', 'lat', 'houseInfo')}
```

==============

```
def serializer_factory(model, base=BaseHyperlinkedModelSerializer,
                       fields=None, exclude=None):
    attrs = {'model': model}
    if fields is not None:
        attrs['fields'] = fields
    if exclude is not None:
        attrs['exclude'] = exclude

    parent = (object,)
    if hasattr(base, 'Meta'):
        parent = (base.Meta, object)
    Meta = type(str('Meta'), parent, attrs)
    if model:
        class_name = model.__name__ + 'Serializer'
    else:
        class_name = 'Serializer'
    return type(base)(class_name, (base,), {'Meta': Meta, })


class DynamicSerializerMixin(object):
    """
    Mixin that allow to limit the fields returned
    by the serializer.

    Es.
        class User(models.Model):
            country = models.ForeignKey(country)
            username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
            email = models.EmailField()

        class UserSerializer(BaseHyperlinkedModelSerializer):
            country = serializers.Field(source='country.name')


        class MyViewSet(DynamicSerializerViewSetMixin, BaseModelViewSet):
            model = User
            serializer_class = UserSerializer
            serializers_fieldsets = {'std': None,
                                      'brief' : ('username', 'email')
                                      }
    this allow calls like

        /api/v1/user/?serializer=brief

    """
    serializers_fieldsets = {'std': None}
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        ser = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('serializer', 'std')

        fields = self.serializers_fieldsets.get(ser, 'std')

        return serializer_factory(self.model,
                                  self.serializer_class,
                                  fields=fields)
```